# ESP32 iPhone Bluetooth, just a general question

Tags: ios, bluetooth, esp32

I'm writing some code (C++) for ESP32, to act as a BLE beacon. The problem is this: the iPhone doesn't send out its real MAC address, but does a random-generated MAC address, for security. The thing I'm confused about is how do you know if it's a device you've previously paired with?

So let's say I detect a new BLE MAC address, and looking at the manufacturer data I can determine it's an Apple device (first 2 bytes are "4C").

Now I need to know if I've previously paired with that device, so that I can allow the ESP32 to initiate an action (for simplicity let's just say turn on an LED). If that MAC address is in a list of known devices, then I can continue, and if not, I ignore it.

The problem is, if the iPhone is not giving up the real MAC address, the detected MAC address will never match anything. As this is a security situation I'm sure the algorithm for generating those MAC addresses is not known.

To be clear: this code is being written for the ESP32, **not** the iPhone.

Comment: If your ESP32 is a beacon then it doesn't connect to devices; it just advertises an identifier for the phone to discover, however assuming that you are using the term 'beacon' to describe some other behaviour, when two BLE devices have bonded previously, they exchange Identity Resolving Keys (IRKs).  This is used to enable one device to identify another that it has previously connected  to - See 5.4.5 in the [Bluetooth Core Specification](https://www.bluetooth.com/specifications/bluetooth-core-specification/)

Comment: Also, to be pedantic, MAC randomisation is a privacy protection, not a security protection :)

Comment: @Paulw11 Yes, after posting this I read a bunch more and found this to be the case also. It just seems odd to me, because by definition a MAC address is a unique address to identify a network device, so by definition would cause it to fail to connect if changed.

Comment: Normally, yes, but in this case the Bluetooth specification provides the mechanism for a device to identify the real MAC of another once they have been connected (presumably by the user) while hiding the MAC from devices that are just attempting to discover devices for tracking purposes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is in fact not possible to tell if a device has been previously seen, unless you pair and establish a bond with it. Once you pair with the device, long-term keys are exchanged and are used to quickly re-establish the connection.

This is by design. MAC addresses were originally unique, but this allowed tracking people and devices without their consent. You can read more about this in the following ESP-IDF guides:

- [GATT security server walkthrough](https://github.com/espressif/esp-idf/blob/v4.0-rc/examples/bluetooth/bluedroid/ble/gatt_security_server/tutorial/Gatt_Security_Server_Example_Walkthrough.md)
- [GATT security client walkthrough](https://github.com/espressif/esp-idf/blob/v4.0-rc/examples/bluetooth/bluedroid/ble/gatt_security_client/tutorial/Gatt_Security_Client_Example_Walkthrough.md)

Comment: Thank you, I need to sit down and take a longer read of these, rather than just making assumptions.

Answer (score 0):

So are you using esp32 as a beacon? This dose not involve any pairing or iOS MAC addresses. iOS will just be able to listen and the esp32 will not even know someone is "listening" to its broadcast.
Probably iOS application can store which services it is interested to hear to; may looks like pairing.. but it is a high level application managed technique and not any related to what BT standard calls pairing.

Comment: My plan is for home automation via Bluetooth. I have other technologies in place, but wanted to use Bluetooth beacon-like devices in my house. I want to have multiple points that I can measure the RSSI for devices, and so will know their approximate location.